# Failed to show polygon on Google Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I tried to debug this code using Chrome and JSLint for 4 days without any promising. My code should show 2 regions on a Google Map, separated by their `RegionID`

My HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>            

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&region=vi&language=vi">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;

    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.79, 826.694),
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {        
        initialize();
        var model =  [{"ID":946,"Latitude":10.7654200827348,"Longitude":106.681716282384,"RegionID":80},{"ID":947,"Latitude":10.7563117596896,"Longitude":106.685397072824,"RegionID":80},{"ID":948,"Latitude":10.7537788369752,"Longitude":106.68713674361,"RegionID":80},
{"ID":1271,"Latitude":10.8577143149377,"Longitude":106.657884916756,"RegionID":82},{"ID":1272,"Latitude":10.8576257110992,"Longitude":106.657710314914,"RegionID":82},{"ID":1273,"Latitude":10.8575762617472,"Longitude":106.657500586099,"RegionID":82},{"ID":1274,"Latitude":10.8575794962578,"Longitude":106.657309632748,"RegionID":82},{"ID":1275,"Latitude":10.8576187762307,"Longitude":106.65709567219,"RegionID":82}]      
        polygon(model);        
    });
</script>
```

And here is my `polygon` function

```
// Take an array of objects that have lat and lon attribute
function polygon(polygonCoords) {    
    // Initialize    
    // First dimension
    var id = polygonCoords[0].RegionID;
    var long;
    var lat;
    var region = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < polygonCoords.length; i++) {
        if ((id != polygonCoords[i].RegionID) || (i == polygonCoords.length - 1)) {
            // Draw polygon
            // Set path to a polygon along with polygon's option                

            var regionPolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
                paths: region,
                fillColor: "#0000A0",                
                editable: false,                
            });


            // Set to map
            regionPolygon.setMap(map);

            // Reset stuffs
            region.length = 0;
            id = polygonCoords[i].RegionID;
        }
        long = polygonCoords[i].Longitude;
        lat = polygonCoords[i].Latitude;
        region.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long));
    }
}
```

All I receive is just a Google Map without any polygon. I tried deleting the for loop and push to `region` array by one variable and it worked again. It is ridiculous but it is what I've figured out after 4 days.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you what's happening there, but it works for me when I replace

```
region.length=0;
```

with

```
region=[];
```

Comment: Up voting and accepting it cannot convey my gratefulness, good Doctor.